# Automatically assigning variables in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, variable-assignment, inspector

I've made a path finding utility that works just fine. Each node has neighboring nodes assigned to it in  an builtin array, which works really smoothly.
However, at the moment I have assigned all these neighboring nodes manually which is circuitous.

The solution I want to avoid:
1) I could *-and I know how to-* assign these arrays at `function Start()`, however I would not be able to use the fast buitlin arrays and starting the game takes unnecessarily much time.

**The solution I am looking for:**
2) I could assign the builtin variables in a 'bake-like-manner':
I need to run a script outside the game that can interact with the game and assign variables much like the script at the previous solution could, but then store the variables and assign builtins.

I hope I explained everything well.
If anything is unclear I'd be pleased to clarify.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you give an example of how your arrays are manually setup now? Is it just a series of arrays in the inspector?

Comment: Yes. For example: if a certain node has 3 nodes around it can connect to because the paths to them are unobstructed this node would have a builtin array of size 3 containing the neighboring nodes:   
`var neighboringNodes : Transform[];`

Comment: To reconstruct the nodes - are they all indentical, or if not, is there some way to idenitfy them if the node tree was saved? You could have a method to save and reload the entire node list. It would be fast.

Comment: They are unique transforms. I am thinking about writing a function that can fill the arrays and then store that information.   Then I'm only left with finding a way of assigning this data to a suiting builin array outside of the game scene.